# FQL application_active_users_gender

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm tryng to write an app to read some metric of applications.

I can't get any metric : only application_active_users.

Event with the example provided by FB , if i change the metric , nothing is shown. Is it a bug, or im missing something?

Example 1 (working) : https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20metric%2C%20value%20FROM%20insights%20WHERE%20object_id%3D2439131959%20AND%20metric%3D'application_active_users'%20AND%20end_time%3Dend_time_date('2011-06-26')%20AND%20period%3Dperiod('month')&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAA6pD9aSW4MSM5rjt8ditDsdZAYVbpG4A7DDEohNUsp4oug3zwVewyqCUwBdBjs71skLZAbBuvm16vZCKaNcai2uDbhYgZDZD

Example 2( NOT working) : https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20metric%2C%20value%20FROM%20insights%20WHERE%20object_id%3D2439131959%20AND%20metric%3D'application_active_users_gender'%20AND%20end_time%3Dend_time_date('2011-06-26')%20AND%20period%3Dperiod('month')&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAA6pD9aSW4MSM5rjt8ditDsdZAYVbpG4A7DDEohNUsp4oug3zwVewyqCUwBdBjs71skLZAbBuvm16vZCKaNcai2uDbhYgZDZD

The first example is provided by facebook , the second is the same, with changed metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application_active_users_gender can only be used with the period "day". See the documentation below:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#application_users

I've tried this but there are still no results returning. It is possibly a bug.